# scrapy only crawl 1 picture

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I want crawl image of link : "http://vnexpress.net/photo/cuoc-song-do-day/nguoi-trung-quoc-ra-be-boi-danh-mat-chuoc-tranh-nong-3445592.html" but but the code is only crawl a picture (in my computer) and crawl all pictures (in my friend computer). Plese please help me

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from imgur.items import ImgurItem

class ImgurSpider(CrawlSpider):
 name = 'imgur'
 allowed_domains = ['vnexpress.net']
 start_urls = ['http://vnexpress.net/photo/cuoc-song-do-day/nguoi-trung-quoc-ra-be-boi-danh-mat-chuoc-tranh-nong-3445592.html']
# rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/*']), 'parse123')]

def parse(self, response):
    image = ImgurItem()
    # image['title'] = response.xpath(\
    #   "//img[data-notes-url=""]").extract()
    rel = response.xpath("//div[@id='article_content']//img/@src").extract()
    image['image_urls'] = [rel[0]]
    return image
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rel = response.xpath("//div[@id='article_content']//img/@src").extract()
image['image_urls'] = [rel[0]]
```

You take only one link by specifying [0] index.
Try

```
image['image_urls'] = rel
```

You can also split your code to url parsing function, and a callback for downloading the images.